# Computing the correlation of an analyzed stock ticker

Tags: java, multithreading

I have an enum of stock tickers, then from the database I get details for an analysed ticker (stock). In the loop, I compare the details of the analysed ticker to details of the rest of tickers, compute the correlation, then add it to the `treeSet`.

This is my first time using multithreading and I wanted the method executed in a shorter time. I'm not sure about this solution. Could you review my code and judge it?

This is my service:

```
@Service public class StatisticService{

    @Inject
    private StockDetailsRepository stockDetailsRepository;

    @Inject
    private StockRepository stockRepository;

    private List<GpwStockTicker> tickersWithOutOneAnalysed;
    private TreeSet<StockStatistic> correlationTreeSet;
    private double [] closePricesAnalysed;
    private int size;
    private PearsonsCorrelation pearsonsCorrelation;

    public TreeSet<StockStatistic> computePearsonCorrelation(Stock stock, int size) {
        this.size = size;
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
        correlationTreeSet = new TreeSet<>();
        pearsonsCorrelation = new PearsonsCorrelation();
        GpwStockTicker mainTicker = stock.getTicker();
        List<StockDetails> stockDetailsAnalysed = getContent(mainTicker, size);
        closePricesAnalysed = getClosePrices(stockDetailsAnalysed);
        EnumSet<GpwStockTicker> tickers = complementOf(EnumSet.of(mainTicker));
        tickersWithOutOneAnalysed = new ArrayList<GpwStockTicker>(tickers);

        Thread threadOne = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                firstPartTickers();
            }
        });

        Thread threadTwo = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                secondPartTickers();
            }
        });

        threadOne.start();
        threadTwo.start();

        try {
            threadOne.join();
            threadTwo.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println("Time of method (s): "+ (end-start) / 1000.0);
        return correlationTreeSet;
    }

    private void firstPartTickers() {
        for(int i = 0; i< tickersWithOutOneAnalysed.size()/2; i++) {
            calculateCorrelation(i);
        };
    }

    private void secondPartTickers() {
        for(int i = tickersWithOutOneAnalysed.size()/2; i< tickersWithOutOneAnalysed.size(); i++) {
            calculateCorrelation(i);
        };
    }

    private void calculateCorrelation(int indexOfTicker) {
        GpwStockTicker ticker = GpwStockTicker.valueOf(tickersWithOutOneAnalysed.get(indexOfTicker).name());
        double [] closePricesToCompare = getClosePrices(getContent(ticker, size));
        Double correlation  = pearsonsCorrelation.correlation(closePricesAnalysed, closePricesToCompare);
        StockStatistic stockCorrelation = new StockStatistic(correlation, ticker);
        correlationTreeSet.add(stockCorrelation);
    }

    private List<StockDetails> getContent(GpwStockTicker ticker, int size) {
        return stockDetailsRepository.findByStockTickerOrderByDateDesc(ticker, new PageRequest(1, size)).getContent();
    }

    private double[] getClosePrices(List<StockDetails> stockDetails) {
        double[] closePrices = new double[stockDetails.size()];

        int idx = 0;
        for(StockDetails stds: stockDetails){
            closePrices[idx++] = stds.getClosePrice().doubleValue();
        }

        return closePrices;
    } 
}
```

The main goal was achieved: the time before multithreading was 77.277 sec and after was 43.534 sec. But I would like to know if my way of thinking was good.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
>     private void firstPartTickers() {
>         for(int i = 0; i< tickersWithOutOneAnalysed.size()/2; i++) {
>             calculateCorrelation(i);
>         };
>     }
>
>     private void secondPartTickers() {
>         for(int i = tickersWithOutOneAnalysed.size()/2; i< tickersWithOutOneAnalysed.size(); i++) {
>             calculateCorrelation(i);
>         };
>     }
> ```

You have two almost identical methods.  Is this really necessary?  Consider the following method:

```
    private void calculateTickers(int start, int increment) {
        for (int i = start; i < tickersWithOutOneAnalysed.size(); i += increment) {
            calculateCorrelation(i);
        }
    }
```

Note that I also removed the unnecessary `;` after the `for` loop.

Now you can just call

```
                calculateTickers(0, 2);
                calculateTickers(1, 2);
```

instead of

> ```
>                 firstPartTickers();
>                 secondPartTickers();
> ```

And if you later wanted to do a third thread, you could say

```
                calculateTickers(0, 3);
                calculateTickers(1, 3);
                calculateTickers(2, 3);
```

Comment: Thanks very nice solution! It is so sad that i don't have code review in my current work place.

Answer (score 2):

```
EnumSet<GpwStockTicker> tickers = complementOf(EnumSet.of(mainTicker));
tickersWithOutOneAnalysed = new ArrayList<GpwStockTicker>(tickers);
```

I have no idea why you chose to wrap your perfectly fine `EnumSet` into an `ArrayList`. I mean, I get it that you are merely using the `List` later to retrieve by indices, but I think this is an unnecessary complication arising from the implementation's *limitation*... As mentioned in [mdfst13's](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/93794/27975) answer, how will you scale up with more threads?

The answer: [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html). I've the same answer to another similar question not so long ago [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/92523/27975). Given a suitable implementation of an `ExecutorService`, your code can simply be just:

```
// ExecutorService executorService = Executors.<...>;
List<Future<StockStatistic>> results = new ArrayList<>();
for (GpwStockTicker ticker : complementOf(EnumSet.of(mainTicker))) {
    results.add(executorService.submit(new Callable<StockStatistic>() {
        @Override
        public StockStatistic call() {
            return new StockStatistic(
                    pearsonsCorrelation.correlation(closePricesAnalysed, 
                        getClosePrices(getContent(ticker, size))), ticker);
        }
    });
}
for (Future<StockStatistic> future : results) {
    correlationTreeSet.add(future.get());
}
// remember to shutdown() executorService too
```

The example above is in Java 7, there's a more `Stream`-like way in Java 8 too if you're keen to explore.

Comment: Nice solution too, if i understand it correctly i will implement it in my case. Thanks.